# nginx reverse proxy cache with gzip content and non-gzip content

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm developing a rails web services with ngnix + passenger, and I use reverse proxy cache in nginx. It works quite well and very fast. The problem is that some clients don't support gzip while some others support.

What I found out is that nginx caches the gzip content, therefore if the gzip-supported clients request first, then the non-gzip clients request, the server still returns gzip content even if the client sends the header "Accept-Encoding": "".

```
gzip  on;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss;
```

Do you have to cache them separately by combining the request_uri and header 'Accept-Encoding'?

Answer (score 2):

That could be a fixed bug. At least I do not observe the behavior in 0.8.54. Try to upgrade your nginx if it's not the latest.

Comment: I'm using nginx 0.7.67.

Comment: I'm upgrade to 0.8.54, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

You should add [`$http_accept_encoding`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) to your [cache key](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_key), or use [gunzip module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html).